# know the parameters of the element from his Graphics

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

how do you know the parameters (eg height and width) of the element, if the constructor is passed only his Graphics?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, can you give more details or show some code?

Comment: public function Func(g:Graphics){...here need to get a reference to the parent of g};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can't inspect the width/height of the `Graphics` object. You'll to be passed the `DisplayObject` instance that contains the `.graphics` instance.